# Does it make sense to store hashes with different algorithms in the database?

Tags: php, algorithm, security, encryption, hash

Based off of this article: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

I had somewhat rewritten the hashing functions to be methods in a Hash object... upon instantiation, the algorithm is randomly set (based off of `hash_algos()`) and the pbkdf2 iterations is also randomly set.

**The main question here is: does it improve security? or does it even matter?**

Since the hash result is stored in the DB in the format of ALGORITHM:ITERATIONS:SALT:HASH, the password validation method will always work -- assuming the format doesn't change.

**A secondary question here is: what if we changed the format and somehow saved that in the database?**

Such as: 1234:ALGORITHM:ITERATIONS:SALT:HASH, whereas the position of the numbers in the first set determine the order. 1 could be "Algorithm", 2 could be "Iterations", 3 could be "salt" and 4 could be "hash"... then it could be stored like 4213:HASH:ITERATIONS:ALGORITHM:SALT

So, for example, this can result in:

```
Plain: Kh ÃfZs²Ã–>Ã¢´D®3¢%jÃmKeMÃ8*/ÃY§w(`P~¿G+ZPÃÃÆQ-:£´CaÃ:p-I&Ã\4„JÃ~*1Æf¿^wwÃ|¶
Hash: ripemd320:136696:up3dvlhcEVOmxZCalFeDZLZsxD6CxTzJ:/ZssN0ODowGqjni2dBq31vQUzH0oR9X8

Plain: ‘¡ÃBÃ¥§‰––§¡kÂ!;Qa!xu!¤®[¥Kkp~{†b}ÃRR7pEÂÃÆÃt1Niw¤¦¢P]ÃÃ^âQÂEfÃ‰‚®Q>Ãi«0CpÂBYU‘ÃIXÃi)z§w¿»¢Ãs7
Hash: snefru256:231279:4ZEgsSuWIUqxBwgEw4JX8RCaxU/92Van:/A1VeH47O7fjrf0mulcOwsAj/OdJ4j8B

Plain: ÂZÃn£¨"Ã&vPÃ9iÃÃÃ§Pj²=Ã¬§#Æ[ÃNi¥0R)*¥„Ã…>QIÂ:ÃSÂ4pªœÃ´ÃÃ6.wÃ0(¡0sbÃ!
Hash: tiger160,3:382995:apCegFYSKwOxCvw70UBO0Cby8ygTLomP:O9kFigaw0X4S9A7pMq559S4NnF5EaZnX

Plain: d'(ÃY¥TÃÃFyfp!Ã~…GÃ
Hash: crc32:166154:b+LONmP+yai0yVSdhtY1+A6waInJaSIQ:eHCD+3sDw16uh1M7eVHTP6zVQ1qvpgP/
```

etc. etc.

Here's the code I used below, they all validate because of the structure of the hash in the DB.

```
<?php
/*
* Password Hashing With PBKDF2 (http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).
* Copyright (c) 2013, Taylor Hornby
* All rights reserved.
*
* Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
* modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
*
* 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
* this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
*
* 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
* this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
* and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
*
* THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
* AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
* IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
* ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
* LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
* CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
* SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
* INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
* CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
* ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
* POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
*/

final class Hash {
  private $PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM = null,
          $PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 128000;

  const PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE = 24;
  const PBKDF2_HASH_BYTE_SIZE = 24;
  const HASH_SECTIONS         = 4;
  const HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX  = 0;
  const HASH_ITERATION_INDEX  = 1;
  const HASH_SALT_INDEX       = 2;
  const HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX     = 3;

  /**
  * On instantiation, randomly set the algorithm to use (based on the available algorithms)
  * and randomly set the iteration count. High iteration counts can cause a high delay in server response.
  */
  public function __construct() {
    $algos = hash_algos();
    $algo  = $algos[mt_rand(0, count($algos) - 1)];
    $this->PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM = $algo;
    $this->PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = mt_rand(128000, 512000);
  }

  public function create_hash($password) {
    // format: algorithm:iterations:salt:hash
    $salt = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(self::PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
    return $this->PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM . ":" . $this->PBKDF2_ITERATIONS . ":" .  $salt . ":" .
    base64_encode($this->pbkdf2(
      $this->PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM,
      $password,
      $salt,
      $this->PBKDF2_ITERATIONS,
      self::PBKDF2_HASH_BYTE_SIZE,
      true
    ));
  }

  public function validate_password($password, $correct_hash) {
    $params = explode(":", $correct_hash);
    if(count($params) < self::HASH_SECTIONS)
      return false;
    $pbkdf2 = base64_decode($params[self::HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX]);
    return $this->slow_equals(
      $pbkdf2,
      $this->pbkdf2(
        $params[self::HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX],
        $password,
        $params[self::HASH_SALT_INDEX],
        (int)$params[self::HASH_ITERATION_INDEX],
        strlen($pbkdf2),
        true
      )
    );
  }

  // Compares two strings $a and $b in length-constant time.
  private function slow_equals($a, $b) {
    $diff = strlen($a) ^ strlen($b);
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($a) && $i < strlen($b); $i++) {
      $diff |= ord($a[$i]) ^ ord($b[$i]);
    }
    return $diff === 0;
  }

  /*
  * PBKDF2 key derivation function as defined by RSA's PKCS #5: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt
  * $algorithm - The hash algorithm to use. Recommended: SHA256
  * $password - The password.
  * $salt - A salt that is unique to the password.
  * $count - Iteration count. Higher is better, but slower. Recommended: At least 1000.
  * $key_length - The length of the derived key in bytes.
  * $raw_output - If true, the key is returned in raw binary format. Hex encoded otherwise.
  * Returns: A $key_length-byte key derived from the password and salt.
  *
  * Test vectors can be found here: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6070.txt
  *
  * This implementation of PBKDF2 was originally created by https://defuse.ca
  * With improvements by http://www.variations-of-shadow.com
  */
  protected function pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false) {
    $algorithm = strtolower($algorithm);
    if(!in_array($algorithm, hash_algos(), true))
      trigger_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.', E_USER_ERROR);
    if($count <= 0 || $key_length <= 0)
      trigger_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid parameters.', E_USER_ERROR);

    if (function_exists("hash_pbkdf2")) {
      // The output length is in NIBBLES (4-bits) if $raw_output is false!
      if (!$raw_output) {
        $key_length = $key_length * 2;
      }
      return hash_pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output);
    }

    $hash_length = strlen(hash($algorithm, "", true));
    $block_count = ceil($key_length / $hash_length);

    $output = "";
    for($i = 1; $i <= $block_count; $i++) {
      // $i encoded as 4 bytes, big endian.
      $last = $salt . pack("N", $i);
      // first iteration
      $last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);
      // perform the other $count - 1 iterations
      for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
        $xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
      }
      $output .= $xorsum;
    }

    if($raw_output)
      return substr($output, 0, $key_length);
    else
      return bin2hex(substr($output, 0, $key_length));
  }
}

/**
* Testing
*/
$start = microtime(true);

// generate a random string
function randString($length, $charset='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789`~!@#$%^&*()_+=-[]\{}|:";\'<>?,./âäàåçêëèïîìÄÅÉæÆôöòûùÿÖÜ¢£¥₧ƒáíóúñÑªº¿') {
  $str = '';
  $count = strlen($charset);
  while ($length--) {
    $str .= $charset[mt_rand(0, $count-1)];
  }
  return $str;
}

set_time_limit(0);

// array of plain and hashed values
$stored = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $plain = randString(mt_rand(10, 100));

  $Hash  = new Hash;
  $hash  = $Hash->create_hash($plain);
  echo "Plain: $plain<br>Hash: $hash<br>";

  // store to check later
  $stored[] = array("plain" => $plain, "hash" => $hash);
}

// check hashes
echo "<hr>";
foreach($stored as $single) {
  $Hash = new Hash;
  $valid = $Hash->validate_password($single['plain'], $single['hash']);
  echo "Valid? ".($valid ? "Yes" : "No")."<br>";
}

echo "<br>Time taken: ".round((microtime(true)-$start), 4)."s";
?>
```

Does any of this really even matter? Does it help the level of entropy?

Comment: IMHO, it wouldn't do a thing. You are still listing the algorithm. Someone could easily just pull that out and split it into groups by algorithm and work on one at a time if they wanted.

Comment: `crypt()` already does this. the hash/version used in producing the actual hash data is embedded into the resulting hash string: http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/crypt. But the only time you'd need to actually store hash details if you are supporting multiple hash types, or multiple versions of the same hash.

Comment: If you have to ask... probably not a good idea. You should use the [`password` extension](http://php.net/password). If you use PHP <5.5.0 then you can use the [compatibility library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer the questions in order:

1. No it does not help security, it actually weakens it. An attacker can simply select an entry with low iteration count and a easy to speed up hash algorithm and attack that.
2. The format of the data does not matter. The security is in the values, not in the format. I would recommend to choose one secure hash algorithm (say SHA-256 if available) and a high enough iteration count.

It would be a good idea to store some kind of version number with the hash to allow updating your scheme *per entry* at a later date. Normally you can only increase safety when the user offers you his password.

Comment: Be warned that if you save binary data (e.g. the output of the PBKDF2)  as string that you may lose bits. Now the format does not matter, but you should not lose bits, use base 64 if you need to store binary results in a character string.

Comment: Indeed. Base64 encoding is being used.